# For any bounded set $A$ in a metric space $(X,d)$, $A$ is inside $B(x,\epsilon)$ for any $x\in X$ and for some $\epsilon>0$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

The idea came to my mind from $\mathbb R^n$, if a set $A$ is bounded there, then you can find a ball centered at $\vec 0$ which consists $A$.

Since $X$ is arbitrary metric space. So there is no unique element as $0$ (by saying unique element, it is unique and special in our hearts). Ergo, I should be able to do it for arbitrary elements in $X$.

Attempt:

Fix any $x_0\in X$ and let $A$ be bounded in $X$. So there is a ball centered at, say $a_0\in A$, for some $\epsilon_0$

$$A\subset B(a_0,\epsilon_0)$$

Now define $m=\sup\limits_{x\in B(a_0,\epsilon_0)} d(x_0,x)$

So $$A\subset B(a_0,\epsilon_0)\subset B(x_0,m)$$

Is there any amusing mistake? If it is wrong can you give me hint for counter-example? Or directly a counter-example?

Comment: Do you mean “For all $x \in X$ there is an $\epsilon > 0$ such that $A \subset B(x, \epsilon)$” or do you mean “There is an $\epsilon > 0$ such that for all $x \in X$, $A \subset B(x, \epsilon)$”? (The first is correct and the second is wrong.)

Comment: First one yes. .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you did is correct, but a bit too complicated. If $A \subset X$ is bounded then $A \subset B(a_0, r)$ for some $a_0 \in X$ and some $r > 0$.

If $x \in X$ then for all $a \in A$, using the triangle inequality for the metric $d$,
$$
 d(x, a) \le d(x,a_0) + d(a_0, a) < d(x,a_0) + r
$$
so that $A \subset B(x, R)$ with $R = d(x,a_0)+ r$.